# Magento 1.9 - Mage->app()->getRequest()->getParam() not working

Tags: magento-1.9, url, parameter

I am fetching the **URL params** as below.

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('test');
```

Debugging with **echo** before the above statement, it works fine. But placing echo **after this statement** return **nothing**, only a **blank page**.

FYI,
one of the **Mage::app()** is working fine here.

Can anyone help me to sort out this issue?

Comment: in which file you are calling this line ?

Comment: In frontend product detail page.

Comment: Ejilarasan J ! Any update on it ?

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad Your answer working fine... Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following & let me know:

```
$requestParams = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
```